# trouble with "WHERE" when joining multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a little trouble with a query.

I'm building a movie database, It has 3 tables. 1 for movies (tblmovie), 1 for genres (tblgenre), and 1 to connect these 2(tblmoviegenre).

I join these 3 together, so that if I had 3 movies with 3 genre's each, I would get 9 rows.

Now I would like to be able to get a movie that contains certain genre's ( for example the one's with ID 2 and 4), this only works when I do this with one genre, because each row only has 1 genre. Anybody know a work around for this?

So if I try

```
SELECT tblmovie.name as moviename 
FROM tblmovie as m
LEFT JOIN tblmoviegenre as mg
on m.movieID = mg.movieID
LEFT JOIN tblgenre as g
on mg.genreID = g.genreID
WHERE mg.genreID = 2 
AND mg.genreID = 4
```

I get no results, because each row only has 1 genre.

Comment: Post the code you have tried, also table detailed structure and sample data will help a lot

Comment: its a really big query with lots of other table's so it would be kinda messy to post the entire thing.

Comment: do you want to get the whole genres for a certain movie if matched?, this can be done using [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), in the same time, use group_by movie name, that will only show the movie once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try something like this,

```
SELECT  movieName
FROM    tableName a       -- of course you need to provide joins here
WHERE   genreID IN (2,4)
GROUP BY movieName
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

The idea here is to match the number of instances to the total number of genre you have provided.

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT tblmovie.name as moviename 
FROM tblmovie as m
          LEFT JOIN tblmoviegenre as mg
               on m.movieID = mg.movieID
          LEFT JOIN tblgenre as g
               on mg.genreID = g.genreID
WHERE mg.genreID IN (2,4) 
GROUP BY tblmovie.name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: did you try the query above? you need to count the instances.

Answer (score 1):

Use `IN` clause instead of `AND` clause:

```
SELECT tblmovie.name as moviename 
FROM tblmovie as m
     LEFT JOIN tblmoviegenre as mg
          ON m.movieID = mg.movieID
     LEFT JOIN tblgenre as g
          ON mg.genreID = g.genreID
WHERE mg.genreID IN(2,4)
GROUP BY tblmovie.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT genreID) = 2;
```

Comment: I tried it, but It didn't work because now I can be either one of them , I need the movie to have both genre's.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give OR instead of AND in the sql query.

Comment: Then the movie could be of either genre, I need the movie to have atleast both of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
SELECT tblmovie.name as moviename 
FROM tblmovie as m
LEFT JOIN tblmoviegenre as mg on m.movieID = mg.movieID
                              and mg.genreID in(2,4) 
LEFT JOIN tblgenre as g       on  mg.genreID = g.genreID
```

Comment: this wouldn't work since the movie could then be of either genre.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following query will work in the situation.

```
SELECT tblmovie.movieName , tblgenre.genereName
FROM tblmoviegenre
WHERE tblmovie.id=tblmoviegenre.tblmovie_id AND tblgenre.id=tblmoviegenre.tblgenre_id
```

Comment: hy can you give the schema in sqlfiddle ?